# Magento Shopping Cart Products not in input order

Tags: magento, admin

The company i work for running Magento 1.7.0.2 with a Cart2quote extension.

They are getting frustrated because when they add a list of products to an order in admin the products dont stay in the order that they were inputted.

Example By SKU:

Order inputted-

D707
E018
P883
P882

Order when finished inputting-

D707
P882
P883
E018

I have only used 4 as an example, although more often than not it can be in excess of 50+ products.

Could this be due to an extension confilct with cart2quote or is there some other soloution?

Sometimes, buy pressing "Updates items and qtys" it does put them in a reverse order (first product is last) and they can live with that.

But as it is now, its making it frustrating for them to double check they have inputted the correct items.

Im sorry to waffle on, but any comments would be appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Dale.

Comment: Why don't you try cart2quote alternative https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this extension, but check created time, updated time, id, etc when sorting.